# I have an Uncaught TypeError when I want to take a screenshot with html2canvas

Tags: javascript, screen, screenshot, html2canvas

I want to take screenshot of my application with html2canvas, but it take a lot of time because of some errors that it create.

I have an Uncaught TypeError that are created by the custom elements that are on the project.

[image: (Console)]

Here is how I made the screenshot in my pop up :

```
window.open_report = async () => {
  try {
    const canvas = await html2canvas(document.body)
    screenshotData = canvas.toDataURL('image/png')
    screenshotPreview.src = screenshotData
    screenshotPreview.style.display = 'block'
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Screen capture error:', error)
  }
}
```

and here is how I import html2canvas with express :

```
app.use('/js/lib/html2canvas.js', express.static('node_modules/html2canvas/dist/html2canvas.esm.js'))
```

Someone has any ideas?

Comment: more context needed

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.